# Secure Data android

Tags: android

I am working on project which contains large amount of data (almost 5 GB videos and Mp3).
and we are manufacturing dedicated Android device for this application.

Right Now I made application where data is store in phone internal memory and I am using path of files in my application.

My problem is that I am not able to figure out, How do I secure my data (video and Mp3) So nobody can copy it from device.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have using homomorphic encryption (infeasible), then it is impossible to fully protect against piracy of your video and mp3 data. In order to play the mp3/video on the phone, you need to unencrypt it some point. Once this occurs, the plain mp3/video file exists in memory. An experienced opponent can steal this.

One option:

- Distribute the app with encrypted Media
- Do not distribute the encryption key with the App
- Fetch the key over a secure connection from one of your servers
- Use the key to unencrypt the Media
- Caveat: someone can leak the key?
- Caveat: the media and the key both exist in memory at some point, and can be stolen by a skilled opponent

Post Jelly Bean, applications distributed via Google Play have some copy protection. However, it sounds like you aren't using Google Play.

Another option: if you don't want to set up servers to fetch the key from, look at the Android team's blog post on [making apks more tamperproof](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html).